# I accidentaly synced wrong VS Code settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, restore

I was trying to sync my settings and extensions in vs Code from my computer to a lap top, and i synced a settings and extensions from lap top to a computer(where i got all the extensions and settings), and now all of my extensions are gone. Can i undo the sync, or at least see my previous VS Code extensions?

Comment: what is the need for the SHOUT at the end of the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go on the machine that you had the extensions, backups are made and kept locally for 30 days.

This should help: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_restoring-data

Comment: Thanks man. You saved me and my setup environment. MUCH APPRECIATED!